# Understanding namespace when using Javascript from Ipython.core.display in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: javascript, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am having trouble understanding the namespace of the `Javascript` function that is provided in IPython.

```
from IPython.core.display import display, Javascript
display(Javascript(u"""
var variable = 'Hello'
console.log(variable)
"""))
[output]
Hello
```

The above seems to work fine, but the following throws an error.

```
display(Javascript(u"""
var variable = 'Hello'
"""))
display(Javascript(u"""
console.log(variable)
"""))
[output]
Javascript error adding output!
ReferenceError: variable is not defined
See your browser Javascript console for more details.
```

If I want to save data into a variable in one function, from say an ajax call, and use it from another function in a separate cell later in a jupyter notebook, what is the best practice method for doing this? My current implementation uses the `Window` to store the variable.

```
display(Javascript(u"""
var variable = 'Hello'
Window.variable = variable
"""))
display(Javascript(u"""
console.log(Window.variable)
"""))
[output]
Hello
```

Another related question - even after storing it in `Window`, I'm unable to access the variable from the javascript console. I'd also like access to it from the javascript console for debugging, but would like to use best practices going forward. Suggestions?

Edit :

The following seems to work fine.

```
display(HTML(u"""

<script>
variable='Hello'
</script>
"""))

display(HTML(u"""

<script>
console.log(variable)
</script>
"""))
```

Comment: Each JS output runs separately in a function namespace, so variables set by one are discarded when it finishes. If you need a global variable, attaching it to `window` is a reasonable way to go. You could also create an HTML element with a unique ID and attach data to that.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation!