# How to run javascript with no filename

Tags: javascript, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am new to coding so I have a question regarding Jupyter Notebook and the use of Javascript. A snippet of my current code is as follows (trueName is defined prior to this code and `pickle.dump` is usually tabbed, but isn't here due to stack overflow's formatting):

---

```
%%javascript
var kernel = Jupyter.notebook.kernel;
console.log(kernel);
var command = "import pickle" + "\n" + "file_name = 'testfile'" + "\n" + "with open(file_name, 'wb') as my_file_obj:" + "\n" + "pickle.dump(trueName,my_file_obj)";
kernel.execute(command);
```

---

This works fine but for some reason when I place it into the following format:

```
from IPython.core.display import Javascript
Javascript("""
var kernel = Jupyter.notebook.kernel;
console.log(kernel);
var command = "import pickle" + "\n" + "file_name = 'testfile'" + "\n" + "with open(file_name, 'wb') as my_file_obj:" + "\n" + " "pickle.dump(trueName,my_file_obj)";
kernel.execute(command);""")
```

I obtain the following error even though the code is the same:

> Javascript error adding output!
>   SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
>   See your browser Javascript console for more details.

---

I had hoped to use the second method in order to bypass the magic command barrier in using something similar to `!ipython somefile.ipy`
to read the javascript, but for some reason the second method really doesn't like the `var command` something I discovered after much testing. I have a few questions that I would greatly appreciate if I received some feedback on:

1. Why does the second method provide an error due to my `var command`? I cannot figure out why this happens.(Is it true that I have to use 'textarea'? If so, how do I do this? I became lost when trying to do so myself: [How to force a line break on a Javascript concatenated string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357846/how-to-force-a-line-break-on-a-javascript-concatenated-string))
2. Is there a method for me to run Javascript magic when not directly in the notebook? I have tried running ipython on the code in a separate file with the `.ipy` ending as seen above, but it does not like running the cell magic nor the import from IPython.core.display. (This method does not work for me: [How to run an IPython magic from a script (or timing a Python script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361206/how-to-run-an-ipython-magic-from-a-script-or-timing-a-python-script))
3. Is there a way for me to execute Javascript code directly (not via a file) when using a function such as  `def run_javascript(code):`? Executing a cell in Jupyter gives back the code within under the argument `code`, but I cannot find out how to run it. I have been looking around but the only answers I have found are about `!node somefile.js` and other similar filename based Javascript codes.
   I would appreciate any help! I did have a few suggestions as to how to run python code as I would like to, but since IPython doesn't work with the Javascript I am at a loss (Python Tips: [run a python script in terminal without the python command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587877/run-a-python-script-in-terminal-without-the-python-command) [Execute python commands passed as strings in command line using python -c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768584/execute-python-commands-passed-as-strings-in-command-line-using-python-c))

Answer (score 1):

This should work, when you use `from IPython.core.display import Javascript` this is a class that when evaluated stores the data returned in scopes and once returned the data is no longer available. Use `window.variable` to assign in to a window object to make it available globally.

```
from IPython.core.display import Javascript
    Javascript("""
    var kernel = Jupyter.notebook.kernel;
    window.variable = kernel;
    var command = "list";
    window.variable = command;
    console.log(kernel.execute(command));""")
```

I got the idea from here

[Understanding namespace when using Javascript from Ipython.core.display in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538578/understanding-namespace-when-using-javascript-from-ipython-core-display-in-jupyt)